# Display multiple MyObject.Name in a single row of a datagridviewCell using Winforms and C#

Tags: c#, winforms

So basically I have a list of people in one datagridview, and the user is to drag and drop the names into another datagridviews cell to make teams of three.  I can capture the Object in the second datagridview, I just can't seem to display the name, it wants to display the Object type

I have an Class named MyObject.  MyObject has a number of properties one is "Name"

I have a datagridview "TeamOfObjects" which I allow users to drop objects from another datagridview "AllObjects" .  The Objects will always be of type MyObject.

AllObjects contains one myObject per Row, TeamOfObjects should contain 1 myObject per cell, 3 cells in a row.  Easy enough to do.

The Problem is that TeamOfObjects displays "MyObject" and not the "Name" Property of MyObject.
I did set the DataProperty to "Name".  I know I can format this to simply use Name instead of the whole object, but at some point I need to read back in the objects that were selected to make the teams

I'm sure this is easy, I've been out of the programming world for a while and I am sure I am just forgetting something.

**** EDIT ****

```
Class MyObject
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    int age {get; set;}
    myObject(string _name, int _age)
    {
        Name=_name;
        Age=_age;
    }
```

}

in my datagridview if you left click on a cell the cell value becomes an iteration of the My Object class

This represents my datagrid view

```
[Person 1 Name][Person 2 Name][Person 3 Name]
[             ][             ][             ]
```

When you click on each of the three empty cells

```
dgv_MouseClick(object sender, datagridviewmouseevents e)
{
    string _name="";
    if (e.col == 0)
        _name = "John";
    else if (e.col == 1)
        _name = "Frank";
    else if (e.col == 2)
        _name = "Suzanne";
    dgv.Rows[e.Row].Cells[e.col].value=new MyObject(_name, 35);
}
```

This is what I Want to happen

```
[Person 1 Name][Person 2 Name][Person 3 Name]
[     John    ][   Frank     ][    Suzanne  ]
```

This is what is happening

```
[Person 1 Name][Person 2 Name][Person 3 Name]
[  MyObject   ][   MyObject  ][   MyObject  ]
```

Comment: JohnG I did not post the myObject Class because I don't believe it was relevant, I could have posted something Generic but really the one property "Name" was all that mattered, the rest would be superfluous.

Comment: JohnG in your second comment, I appreciate your effort to illicit more information but I am afraid I do not follow what you are trying to tell me.  I am busy at this moment but I will try to add some code to the question above including a demo class to try to explain my case better

Comment: JohnG Major edit in my question, hopefully I have addressed your questions to me

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the specific issue I currently have however it is only specific to one property and cannot be used to display mutliple properties of the Object in different cells or even different Datagridviews.  I am still holding out hoping someone has a better solution.

override the ToString Method in the MyObject Class

```
public override string ToString() 
{
   return Name;
}
```